# Background process, with stdin a pipe connected to fd 3 in the parent shell script

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, sh, posix

Is it possible, in portable shell, *without* using a named pipe, to start a background process and have that process's stdin be a pipe which is open on file descriptor 3 (or some other number greater than 2) in the parent shell?  Another way to put it is that I want to do in portable shell what `popen("some-program", "w")` does in C.

Concretely, do what this snippet does, without using `mkfifo`:

```
mkfifo fifo
some-program < fifo &
exec 3> fifo
rm fifo
```

Note: "bash" tag added primarily for visibility.  I understand that this is possible [using the "coprocess" extension in bash, ksh, or zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372); I am looking for a technique that works in an environment where *only* the facilities of [XPG Issue **6** (POSIX.1-**2001**) Shell and Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities) are available.  In addition, answers that use a named pipe (via `mkfifo` most obviously) will not be accepted, as will answers that require `root` privileges.

Answers that use any of the following are discouraged, but I'll listen to an argument that it's not possible to do it without one or more of them:

- anything that creates a machine-language executable (e.g. `c99`)
- anything intended primarily for interactive use (e.g. `vi`)
- anything that's not part of the "Base" spec in Issue 6, or is obsolescent in either Issue 6 or any later revision of POSIX (e.g. `uucp`)

I'll also listen to an answer that makes a convincing argument that this is impossible within the restrictions above.

(Why no named pipes? Because they don't behave quite the same as normal pipes, particularly with the older, buggier OSes where "just use `#!/bin/bash`" isn't an option.  Also, exposing the pipe in the file system, however briefly, means you cannot completely exclude the possibility of some unrelated process opening the pipe.)

Comment: Even though you specify Posix shell and use the [sh] tag correctly  (I guess) , I'd recommend adding a `[bash]` tag, as you will get many more readers to your Q. (I'm also leaving a comment to see what the super-shell crowd can offer). I think what you have shown is the correct use-case. Good luck.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. An a bit more elaborate example might help here.

Comment: @kvantour I'm not sure how to explain it more clearly than I already did, but does it help if I say "basically I want to be able to do in shell what `popen` does in a C program"?

Comment: Do you want a pure `sh` solution or a pure posix solution? (`mkfifo` is part of posix https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: @kvantour I want a solution that uses no extensions to the `sh` spec -- no `ksh`, `bash`, etc. features -- *and* that does not use `mkfifo`.

Comment: Just to be clear, you would like to have a solution which is fully POSIX compliant and written in pure shell syntax, without the use of additional binaries, even if they are part of POSIX.

Comment: @kvantour I have attempted to clarify my requirements.

Comment: @zwol The closest AFAIK (not POSIX compatible) could be [Coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) in Bash and for other shells, see [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372) on Unix.SE

Comment: Don't think there is one thats compatible across the shells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be backgrounded *per se*, and can you tolerate a different parent process?

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ -z "$REINVOKED" ]; then
  # First time we're running.
  # Save our stdout and launch some-program on a pipe connected to
  # our second invocation.  (A new shell will replace this one.)
  exec 4>&1
  REINVOKED=true
  export REINVOKED
  exec /bin/sh -c "$0 | some-program"  # <- WARNING
  exit 1
fi

# Second invocation.
#
exec 3>&1    # dup the pipe (our stdout) to fd3
exec 1>&4    # restore stdout from inherited fd4
exec 4>&-    # close fd4

echo "READY"     # goes to stdout
echo "READY" >&3 # goes to some-program
...
```

That dodgy environment variable usage to detect a second invocation of the script could be more robustly reimplemented as separate scripts.  The *WARNING* line is where you will need to watch future revisions for command injection ([CWE-78](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html)).

The processes ancestry will look like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "/rather/dodgy.sh | some-program"
   |
   +- /bin/sh -c /rather/dodgy.sh
   |
   +- some-program
```

All in the same process group, and presumably spawned from your interactive shell (`-bash` ?).

Answer (score 2):

The only standard shell feature that provides for creating pipes is the `|` operator.  If we assume no extensions are in play, then [the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12) says that the commands in a (multi-command) pipeline execute in subshell environments.  Such an environment cannot modify the parent shell so as to make a file descriptor for the write end of the pipe available there, so the closest we can come is to make it available within the scope of a `{ compound-command }` on the write end of the pipe.  Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 4>&1

{
  # Copy the write end of the pipe to FD 3, restore the parent
  # shell's original stdout, and close excess FD 4
  exec 3>&1 1>&4 4>&-
  
  use-fd-3-here
} | something-goes-here

exec 4>&-
```

Now, although it can be redirected, the initial standard input to an asynchronous command is (an equivalent of) `/dev/null`, so it won't work to put just `some-command &` on the read end of the pipe. But we can put another compound command around `some-command`, to give us a place to make a copy of the standard input file descriptor from the pipe.  Example:

```
{
  some-command 0>&4 4>&-
} 4>&0 &
```

Those work together just fine.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copy the standard output FD to preserve access to it within processes in the
# pipeline
exec 4>&1

{
  # Rotate file descriptors:
  #  - the write end of the pipe becomes 3
  #  - the parent shell's standard output becomes 1
  #  - excess FD 4 is closed for tidiness and safety
  exec 3>&1 1>&4 4>&-

  # This is piped into the standard input of a command running asynchronously.
  # In this example, that process will substitute a "!" for the "?" and output
  # the result
  echo 'piped?' 1>&3

  # This does not go to the async process
  echo 'not piped?'
} | {
  # Redirect the read end of the pipe to this process's standard input and
  # clean up the extra file descriptor.
  sed 's/?/!/' 0>&4 4>&-
} 4>&0 &

exec 4>&-

# wait for the async process to terminate
wait
```

Output:

> not piped?
> piped!

And if you were concerned about the relative order of the `4>&0` redirection and redirecting `/dev/null` to the standard input of the async process, then a little more compound-command declaration could make that unambiguous:

```
 | {
     {
       some-command 's/?/!/' 0>&4 4>&-
     } &
} 4>&0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to `popen("some-program", "w")` and send data to it through *fd3* with a POSIX shell:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
{
    {
        # MAIN PROGRAM (basically, the whole script goes here)
        echo "normal output that won't be processed by some-program"
        echo 'some input for some-program' 1>&3
    } 3>&1 1>&4 |
    some-program
} 4>&1
```

Regarding the *background* part of the question: with the above construct, `some-program` is running in a sub-process; so, unless you need to detach `some-program` from its parent group (ie. `setpgid(0, 0)`), then there's no need to use any `&` in the shell.

Comment: The trick is that the read end of the pipe is accessed by a *background* process.  Background processes initially have (an equivalent of) `/dev/null` as their standard input.  They can redirect that, and it looks like that would be necessary in a solution to the problem posed, but they can't take it directly from a pipe.